# How to add comment using cell property in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to add comment using cell property, like i need to add comment to Cells(1, i).

I know how to add comment using Range property (Range("A1").AddComment), but i wanted to add through cells property. Please help in excel vba.

```
Sub t()
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

headers() = Array("FIRST", "Second", "Third")
For i = 1 To 3
m = Cells(1, i).Value
If Cells(1, i).Value <> headers(i - 1) Then
Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Cells(1, i).AddComment 'I need to add some text here"

MsgBox ("Not equal")
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(1,i).AddComment`?

Comment: that is not working, i tried. Its showing following error message : Run-time error '1004':
Appliation-defined or object-defined error.      Also I am not sure how to pass the Comment Text. Please help me

Comment: Please show the code you are trying.

Comment: Sub t()
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

headers() = Array("FIRST", "Second", "Third")
For i = 1 To 3
m = Cells(1, i).Value
If Cells(1, i).Value <> headers(i - 1) Then
Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Cells(1, i).AddComment 'I need to add some text here"

MsgBox ("Not equal")
End If
Next i

End Sub

Comment: Not in the comments.  Put the code in the Original Post using [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've just posted, all you're missing is a string after the `AddComment` method. **Edit**: you probably already have comments in some of the target cells. I've added a call to ClearComments.

```
Sub t()
    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Variant

    headers() = Array("FIRST", "Second", "Third")

    For i = 1 To 3
        m = Cells(1, i).Value
        If Cells(1, i).Value <> headers(i - 1) Then
            Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Cells(1, i).ClearComments
            Cells(1, i).AddComment "Hello World" '<===== Here
            MsgBox ("Not equal")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: its not working for me. showing error message "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" in cells(1,i).addcomment "hello" line. Please help me

Comment: @Rick You must test that the cell doesn't have a comment already before attempting to add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may concern, the problem is if you already have a comment, then you have to delete it before you can add more comments. Simply add the following before you addcomment:

```
**Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Cells(row_num, col_num)
If Not (rng.comment Is Nothing) Then
    rng.comment.Delete
End If**

rng.AddComment (in_comment)
```

Comment: It seems to me that vba should accept rng.Comment.Delete regardless of whether a comment exists or not.  The existence test should be subsumed into the Delete implementation.  An existence test in the calling VBA just clutters the caller's VBA code.
I am presuming of course, that the Delete code tests for existence internally before attempting to delete. If you implemented the Delete code, wouldn't you? And if it does, forcing caller to test is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you have to do:

Cells(1, i).address.AddComment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).